# Is there any way to optimise these for loops in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have some code here (used for gradient calculation) - Example values are commented:

```py
dE_dx_strided = np.einsum('wxyd,ijkd->wxyijk', dE_dy, f)
# dE_dx_strided.shape = (64, 25, 25, 4, 4, 3)

imax, jmax, di, dj = dE_dx_strided.shape[1:5]
# imax, jmax, di, dj = (25, 25, 4, 4)

dE_dx = np.zeros_like(x)
# dE_dx.shape = (64, 28, 28, 3)

for i in range(imax):
    for j in range(jmax):
        dE_dx[:, i:i+di, j:j+dj, :] += dE_dx_strided[:, i, j, ...]
```

where `dE_dx` is the object of interest and `dE_dx_strided` is a 6-tensor which is being summed over 'piecewise', effectively, and it looks reminiscent of a convolution operation along axes `1` and `2`:

```
# Verbose convolution operation (not my actual implementation)
for i in range(imax):
    for j in range(jmax):
        # Vaguely similar, but with filter multiplication, and = instead of +=
        y[i, j] = x[i:i+di, j:dj] * f[di, dj]
```

My original idea was to make all elements of `dE_dx_strided` that are to be added to a single `dE_dx[:, i:i+di, j:j+dj, :]` lie along one axis, and then sum over it; but I couldn't get this to work.

Now I know that `for` loops aren't inherently slow, but is there a numpy-esque way to optimise this further, perhaps by reshaping, summing, strides, etc.?

Comment: This looks like a convolution of sorts - `scipy.signal` might have something useful.

Comment: Please provide us with example data. Some of your values are not clear in the code and makes it hard to help. A minimal reproducible example would be great.

Comment: @Ehsan sorry about that - please see edits